# how to change the scale of vector?

Tags: algorithm, scale, data-processing

I have a vector A, can we scale into ( 1,10)??

A=[0.06968048677109477,
     0.07091805084676589,
     0.07506590429005261,
     0.09044325046970765,
     0.0908465379725413,
     0.10471009623683523,
     0.10539538950750547,
     0.1056711444959778,
     0.1058978683826518,
     0.1060517166406799,
     0.10666426409947774,
     0.106760038969985,
     0.10684882498871025,
     0.10708945255736063,
     0.10720561359279776
     0.12979174345223443,
     0.13562228877496077,
     0.13563624887480935,
     0.13597957216781367,
     0.13622839687165716,
     0.1364550028417469,
     0.13711208167062497,
     0.13781207673985127,
     0.1382417752997873,
     0.13829000163905658,
     0.14263838186789873,
     0.14366697585135071,
     0.1445867019056321,
     0.1495675689904077,
     0.15003042280326156,
     0.16038058859231508,
     0.1606127314494579,
     0.16244828451643853,
     0.16370120071381172,
     0.1639400518074859]

Answer (score 0):

Get the minimum and maximum values in `A`.

The scale factor will then be:

```
factor = (10.0 - 1.0) / (max - min);
```

To each value `v` in `A` you will transform by a scaling function:

```
v = 1.0 + ((v - min) * factor)
```